# magento add tax on custom attribute based price

Tags: magento, attributes

we sell bunch of product and we need to display each price product and entire box price.For that reason i have created attribute with each price and calling it on product page.So main price of product will be box price and each price will be display from attribute.but now i when i add tax i can see the main price with excluding and including tax but how to apply that tax on attribute based price?

this would be each product price

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('each_price')->getFrontend()-  >getValue($_product)?>
```

this would be whole box price

```
   <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this can be done to achive this.please look the code below

```
  <?php $txrate= $_product->getData('tax_percent');
                   if($txrate!=""):
                   echo '<div class="each-inc-tax">';
                     $ech_price= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('each_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                     $tx=($txrate*$ech_price)/100;
                     $each_tax=$ech_price+$tx;
                     echo  ' <b>Each Price Including Tax:</b> <b>'. $each_tax.'</b>';
                    echo '</div>';
                   endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the MSRP attribute in my magento and storing the value excluding Tax, but wishing to display on the frontend including Tax.

I used the following code...

```
<?php
$_finalPriceExclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice(), false);
$_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);
$_taxpercent = $_finalPriceInclTax / $_finalPriceExclTax;
$_msrpPrice = $_product->getMsrp() * $_taxpercent;
?>
```